# Does Highcharts redraw every time the dataset is changed?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Just curious if this is how Highcharts updates itself or if it does some other sort of magic.

Comment: It's been my experience that it updates when the dataset changes. Highcharts provides a very nice example [here](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm).

Comment: If you are using API function (addSeries, addPoint, etc.) then you can control whether your chart is going to be redrawn (as explained in the top answer), but if you will change some properties manually, then no magic there. So, do you mean API functions? or not?

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts provides an API to alter the data of a Chart:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update

Each of these Methods has one parameter called `redraw` that is used to indicate wether you want to automatically redraw the chart after the update. As it is also stated in the documentation: if one updates a lot of data it may be better to update all the values with this parameter set to false and calling `chart.redraw()` manually afterwards.